# How to filter data in PhpMyAdmin using SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need to filter out a specific date range in PhpMyAdmin for a long list of data. The column is named 'datetime' and each time a new entry goes into the DB, it follows this format:

2015-05-22 23:30:00

So how would I filter a range of dates without having to input the hours/mins/secs? Example:

If I only wanted to see the entries from 2015-01-01  to 2015-02-02?

example SQL line would be:

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE datetime "here's the question. What condition/operator do I use?"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE datetime between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-02-02 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks Jens! Came up with the answer as well. it worked without the 00:00:00 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I found the answer. It seems like phpmyadmin isn't extremely urgent on having to input the time. This is what I did:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-02'
```

So it works even without having to input the h/m/s